# MySQL server has gone away Error in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2

My application was working fine earlier but from last few days giving error as

> **Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away**
>
> **SQL Query**
>
> SELECT Categories.id AS `Categories__id`, Categories.title
>   AS `Categories__title`, Categories.description AS
>   `Categories__description`, Categories.icon AS `Categories__icon`,
>   Categories.c_status AS `Categories__c_status`, Categories.created AS
>   `Categories__created`, Categories.modified AS `Categories__modified`
>   FROM categories Categories WHERE Categories.c_status = 1

and a suggestion

```
 If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.
```

I tried with enabling identifier in `app.php` then also same error.

Source code for generated query

```
$menu_categories = $this->Categories->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
      'Categories.c_status' => 1,
    ],
    'contain' => [
      'Subcategories.ProductTypes' => [
        'conditions' => [
          'ProductTypes.status' => 1,
        ],
      ],
      'CategoryBanners' => [
        'conditions' => [
          'CategoryBanners.status' => 1,
        ],
      ],
    ],
]);
$this->set('menu_categories', $menu_categories);
```

**What could be the cause for the error ?**

Comment: This error is coming straight from MySQL, have you Googled it to see common causes and solutions?

Comment: running query in phpmyadmin is working fine

Comment: Even so, Googling the error message will find you some diagnostics that you can run in MySQL to help narrow down the cause, and knowing the cause should make resolving it easier. Otherwise, all you're going to get here are guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and it turned out to be an issue with the "max_allowed_packet" setting for the database. I increased mine from the default up to 16MB, and it resolved my issue. Something to check on and experiment with if you or anybody else is having this error.